# How to stop repeating myself in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was trying to clean the data I've just scraped, but as I was using the pandas library I used a lot of repeated code. I know the DRY practice in programming, so I wonder if there's any way to refine my code?

```
# Filtering sub_id whose top 100 products' least sales are bigger than 0. 

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import csv

seller_df = pd.read_csv('./shopee_seller_raw.csv')
paren_id_df = pd.ExcelFile('./product_category.xlsx').parse('Sheet1') 

# Drop the NaN data lines in shopee_seller_raw.csv
seller_df = seller_df.dropna(how='any')

# Drop products whose sales is 0
zero_sold_index = seller_df[seller_df['sold'] == 30].index
seller_df.drop(zero_sold_index, inplace=True)

# Function used in the lambda expression
def get_id(string, number, strip):
    return string.split(":")[number].strip(strip)

# Cleaning data in some columns
seller_df['shop'] = seller_df['shop'].apply(lambda x: get_id(x, 1, ","))
seller_df['item'] = seller_df['item'].apply(lambda x: get_id(x, 1, ","))
seller_df['like'] = seller_df['like'].apply(lambda x: get_id(x, 1, ","))
seller_df['view'] = seller_df['view'].apply(lambda x: get_id(x, 1, ","))
seller_df['rate star'] = seller_df['rating'].apply(lambda x: get_id(x, 2, ',"rating_count"'))
seller_df['rate count'] = seller_df['rating'].apply(lambda x: list(get_id(x, 3, ',"rcount_with_image"'))[1])
seller_df['shop'] = pd.to_numeric(seller_df['shop'])
seller_df['item'] = pd.to_numeric(seller_df['item'])
seller_df['like'] = pd.to_numeric(seller_df['like'])
seller_df['view'] = pd.to_numeric(seller_df['view'])
seller_df['rate star'] = pd.to_numeric(seller_df['rate star'])
seller_df['rate count'] = pd.to_numeric(seller_df['rate count'])


# Extract sellers without repetition
sellers = [seller for seller, df in seller_df.groupby(['shop'])]
print(len(sellers))
```

Here are screenshots of my dataset.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: When I find myself with "a lot of repeated code" I look for ways in which I can automate the process I'm working on. Often takes the form of abstracting repeated code into a function, class, module dependent on the nature and magnitude of the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

I can't really tell why rate star and rate count are different from the rest, but if you find a way to access those columns the same way you access the rest, you could really just do something like:

```
columns = ['shop', 'item', 'like', 'view', 'rate star', 'rate count']
for column in columns:
   seller_df[column] = seller_df[column].apply(lambda x: get_id(x, 1, ","))
   seller_df[column] = pd.to_numeric(seller_df[column])
```